# How are the programs in /bin directory compiled into a non-readable format?

Tags: bash, compiling, programming

I've noticed that most of my commands/programs in the /bin directory are compiled. I wish to duplicate this non-readable code format myself. Can someone tell me why and/or how these programs get this way?

[green stamp bonus]: Isn't there a bash command to print all of the "human readable" text from a file?

Comment: Note that not all commands are compiled binaries. Your `/bin` and `/usr/bin/` directories also contain commands that are written in scripting languages like `sh`, `bash`, `perl`, `python`, etc... Try running `file /bin/* | less` in a terminal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The commands/programs in `/bin` are not *non-readable*, but they are, as you say, compiled. This means that they were originally written in C (or some other programming language) and have been compiled to machine code (binary) so the processor can execute the code. To do the same, simply write the program you need in C and run the `gcc` command to produce an executable file.

To print any human readable text in a files use `strings < /bin/file`,

Answer (score 12):

**Introduction**

When a program is compiled from say C or C++ source code, a compiler such as `gcc` (see below) translates that code into the native binary language of the CPU, so that the program can be executed. Thus *human readable material* (source code) is turned into a *non-human readable format* (machine readable binary code).

**Binaries and the Filesystem**

If you enter `echo $PATH`, you will see a locations of all the executables on the system, both compiled binaries and scripts:

```
/home/mike/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

In the filesystem hierarchy key system tools such as `cat` and `getty`  are present in `/bin` and `/sbin` respectively, and other tools such as `dpkg` and `chroot` are present in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` respectively. If you compile a program by downloading the source code, configuring the build, and the installing it, your program by default should go in `/usr/local/bin` and its other files in the `/usr/local` hierarchy.

**Compilers**

Probably one of the most well known tools used to compile binaries is `gcc`, which is known as the GNU Compiler Collection and earlier as the GNU C compiler; the version shipped with Ubuntu 12.04 is `gcc 4.6.3`. As it notes in the offical GNU [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc.pdf),

```
GCC is an integrated distribution of compilers for several major programming 
languages. These languages currently include C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, 
Java, Fortran, Ada, and Go.
```

**Compiling a binary**

The three commands `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` (or `sudo checkinstall`) are often used together in order to compile a program.

Running `./configure`, amongst other things, checks the version of `gcc` installed and prepares the build environment. The `makefile` is one of the most important things generated from running `./configure` as it directs the build when `make` is run. The GNU [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf) details the process in great depth. In sum, the rules in the `makefile` determine the main goal (to create an executable) so that the source code `.c` files will be made into compiled files (`.o` files) in order to generate the target executable file.

**Resources**

Two great resources are these Ubuntu compilation guides [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware), which contain some great advice and information for those new to compiling. Other resources such as the GNU `gcc` manual and the `make` manual I have mentioned already. For more information on C and creating a simple little C program, see chapter 22 of [Rute](http://wireless.ictp.trieste.it/school_2003/docs/linux/rute.pdf) and chapter 24 of the [Linux Command Line](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/09.12/TLCL-09.12.pdf/download).

Answer (score 1):

To compile Bash programs into binaries ( I'm assuming you're asking about Bash because your  question is tagged bash) you should use the program Shc. You can download it from [here](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc-3.8.9.tgz). After you unpack the archive, compile and install **shc** with `cd shc-3.8.9;make;sudo make install`. Now, run `shc -f filename`, where **filename** is the path to the file you want to make into a non-readable code format. Shc will create two files: **filename.x.c** and **filename.x**. You can get rid of **filename.x.c**, filename is the non-readable file.

Comment: There's not much point in compiling bash scripts. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat/CompilingBad

Answer (score 1):

**One Option**:
If you want to see what's in the compiled programs use a tool like objdump to dump out the object code, for example:

```
objdump -d /bin/ls | less
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 different kinds of people. Guess you belong to the second group... :P

There are only binaries in the bin directory (Binaries = Programms in Binary Code, just 1 and 0)

They are compiled to be machine readable. Machines know 1 and 0 or on and off, true or false, nothing else.

This is done by a compiler. There are more than one compiler. I can think of the Gnucc compiler, or the Java-Compiler, or a Delphi-Compiler... Different compilers for different programming languages.

Try grep. Good Luck!

Comment: Not all commands are compiled binaries...

Comment: correct, there are also bash scripts and symlinks in bin directory. Sorry.